# Ratio of the expression and the corresponding description fix in Beamer

Tags: beamer

I want to modify the display of my equation little bit. Below is the code which I used to show the ratio of two expressions and use a pointer for the descrption of the items.

I was able to show the expressions but I was wondering if it is possible to use them as a real fraction just like the expression we get while using `\frac` function.

```
\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]


\begin{equation*}
a_i(t,x) =
        \tikz[baseline]{
            \node[fill=blue!20,anchor=base] (t1)
            {$ \tau C_i(t,x,\tau )\partial \tau$};
        } /
        \tikz[baseline]{
            \node[fill=red!20, ellipse,anchor=base] (t2)
            {$C_i(t,x,\tau) \partial \tau$};
        } 
\end{equation*}


\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
 \item Coriolis acceleration
        \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (n1) {};
    \item Transversal acceleration
        \tikz[na]\node [coordinate] (n2) {};
\end{itemize}

% Now it's time to draw some edges between the global nodes. Note that we
% have to apply the 'overlay' style.
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \path[->]<1-> (n1) edge [bend right] (t1);
        \path[->]<2-> (n2) edge [bend right] (t2);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

The output of the above code is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), complete with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage{...}`'s, `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}`. The code should be compilable without requiring modification.

Comment: This is possible (I just did it.) but I had to add some TikZ library and a package that wasn't mentioned in your "MWE". The result looked dreadful because the shapes overlapped. I think you should stick to a presentation with a reduced wow-this-is-amazing factor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]
\tikzstyle{every picture}=[remember picture]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{equation*}
a_i(t,x) =
        \frac{
        \tikz[baseline]{
            \node[fill=blue!20,anchor=base] (t1)
            {$ \tau C_i(t,x,\tau )\partial \tau$};
        }}{
        \tikz[baseline]{
            \node[fill=red!20, ellipse,anchor=base] (t2)
            {$C_i(t,x,\tau) \partial \tau$};
        }} 
\end{equation*}


\begin{itemize}[<+-| alert@+>]
 \item Coriolis acceleration
        \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (n1) {};
    \item Transversal acceleration
        \tikz[na]\node [coordinate] (n2) {};
\end{itemize}

% Now it's time to draw some edges between the global nodes. Note that we
% have to apply the 'overlay' style.
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \path[->]<1-> (n1) edge [bend left] (t1);
        \path[->]<2-> (n2) edge [bend right] (t2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample image output]

Comment: @ Matthew: Thank you so much for your answer. Actually I had tried using this way, may be the syntax was wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Your upvote and check are thanks enough. `:-)`